# Solution for finding "duplicate" records involving STI and parent-child relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm

I have an STI-based model called Buyable, with two models Basket and Item. The attributes of concern here for Buyable are:

- shop_week_id
- location_id
- parent_id

There's a parent-child relationship between Basket and Item. parent_id is always nil for basket, but an item can belong to a basket by referencing the unique basket id. So basket has_many items, and an item belongs_to a basket.

I need a method on the basket model that:

Returns true of false if there are any other baskets in the table with both the same number of and types of items. Items are considered to be the same type when they share the same shop_week_id and location_id.

For ex:

Given a basket (uid = 7) with 2 items:

item #1

- id = 3
- shop_week_id = 13
- location_id = 103
- parent_id = 7

item #2

- id = 4
- shop_week_id = 13
- location_id = 204
- parent_id = 7

Return true if there are any other baskets in the table that contain exactly 2 items, with one item having a shop_week_id = 13 and location_id = 103 and the other having a shop_week_id = 13 and location_id = 204.  Otherwise return false.

How would you approach this problem? This goes without saying, but I am looking for a very efficient solution.

Comment: Could you please explain why this test is needed? Does it really matter if there are duplicate baskets around? If it is needed because you want to check whether items have been sold that are also in other people baskets, it is only on `item` level. Otherwise I do not quite understand why an identical basket, from a different user would be harmful. If you are looking at buying patterns, I would do that in some kind of off-line/batch process.

Comment: I understand your question. From business or user standpoint, the need for a solution to the above problem involving "shopping" probably would never occur. I'm not dealing with baskets and items in my app / DB. This question represents the general problem that I am having in finding duplicates in a model / table involving STI and parent-child relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify my query, and somewhat vague description of the table columns of the "buyable" table,  The "Parent_ID" is the basket in question.  The "Shop_Week_ID" is the consideration for baskets to be compared... don't compare a basket from week 1 to week 2 to week 3.  The #ID column appears to be a sequential ID in the table, but not the actual ID of the item to be compared... The Location_ID appears to be the common "Item".  In the scenario, assuming a shopping cart, Location_ID = 103 = "Computer", Location_ID = 204 = "Television" (just for my interpretation of the data).  If this is incorrect, minor adjustments may be needed, in addition to the original poster showing a list of say... a dozen entries of the data to show proper correlation.

So, now, on to my query..  I'm doing a STRAIGHT_JOIN so it joins in the order I've listed.

The first query for alias "MainBasket" is exclusively used to query how many items are in the basket in question ONCE, so it doesn't need to be re-joined/queried again for each possible basket to match.  There is no "ON" clause as this will be a single record, and thus no Cartesian impact, as I want this COUNT(*) value applied to EVERY record in the final result.

The NEXT Query is to find a DISTINCT OTHER Basket where at LEAST ONE "Location_ID" (Item) within the same week as the parent in question... This could result in other baskets having 1, same or more entries than the basket.  But if there are 100 baskets, but only 18 have at least 1 entry that matches 1 item in the original basket, you've just significantly cut down the number of baskets to do final compare against (SameWeekSimilar alias result).

Finally is a Join to the buyable table again, but based on a join for the SameWeekSimilar, but only on per "other" basket that had a close match... No specific items, just by the basket.  The query used to get the SameWeekSimilar already pre-qualified the same week, and at least one matching item from the original basket in question, but specifically excluding the original basket so it doesn't compare to itself.

By doing a group at the outer level based on the SameWeekSimilar.NextBasket, we can get the count of actual items for that basket.  Since a simple Cartesian join to the MainBasket, we just grab the original count.

Finally, the HAVING clause.  Since this is applied AFTER the "COUNT(*)", we know how many items were in the "Other" baskets, and how many in the "Main" basket.  So, the HAVING clause is only including those where the counts were the same.

If you want to test to ensure what I'm describing, run this against your table but DO NOT include the HAVING clause.  You'll see which were all the POSSIBLE... Then re-add the HAVING clause and see which ones DO match same count...

```
select STRAIGHT_JOIN
      SameWeekSimilar.NextBasket,
      count(*) NextBasketCount,
      MainBasket.OrigCount
   from 
      ( select count(*) OrigCount
           from Buyable B1
           where B1.Parent_ID = 7 ) MainBasket

      JOIN

      ( select DISTINCT
              B2.Parent_ID as NextBasket
           from
              Buyable B1
                 JOIN Buyable B2
                    ON B1.Parent_ID != B2.Parent_ID
                   AND B1.Shop_Week_ID = B2.Shop_Week_ID
                   AND B1.Location_ID = B2.Location_ID
           where
              B1.Parent_ID = 7 ) SameWeekSimilar

       Join Buyable B1
          on SameWeekSimilar.NextBasket = B1.Parent_ID

    group by
       SameWeekSimilar.NextBasket

    having
       MainBasket.OrigCount = NextBasketCount
```

Answer (score 3):

The following SQL seems to do the trick

```
big_query = "
  SELECT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM buyables b1
      JOIN buyables b2
        ON b1.shop_week_id = b2.shop_week_id
        AND b1.location_id = b2.location_id
    WHERE
      b1.parent_id != %1$d
      AND b2.parent_id = %1$d
      AND b1.type = 'Item'
      AND b2.type = 'Item'
    GROUP BY b1.parent_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM buyables WHERE parent_id = %1$d AND type = 'Item' )
  )
"
```

With ActiveRecord, you can get this result using [select_value](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements/select_value):

```
class Basket < Buyable
  def has_duplicate
    !!connection.select_value( big_query % id )
  end
end
```

I am not so sure about performance however

Comment: `SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ...` might be better.

Comment: @muistooshort You are correct, I've updated the answer. BTW I just noticed that this can return a false positive if items can be duplicated. If that's a problem, another subquery might be needed

Comment: When I try to run your query, I get a syntax error: http://bit.ly/n9Jmkz. I've never seen %1$d syntax myself so not sure what it's trying to do.

Comment: @keruilin The `%1$d` is a placeholder for your basket_id ( see [String#%](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001127) ). `%d` means integer, and the `1$` means "use the 1st argument".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make this as efficient as possible, you should consider creating a hash that encodes basket contents as a single string or blob, add a new column containing the hash (which will need to be updated every time the basket contents change, either by the app or using a trigger), and compare hash values to determine possible equality.  Then you might need to perform further comparisons (as described above) in order

What should you use for a hash though?  If you know that the baskets will be limited in size, and the ids in question are bounded integers, you should be able to hash to a string that is enough in itself to test for equality.  For example, you could base64 encode each shop_week and location, concatenate with a separator not in base64 (like "|"), and then concatenate with the other basket items.  Build an index on the new hash key, and comparisons will be fast.

Comment: Ahh...I really like this idea.  I've used this approach on a similar issue, and it worked well.