# Creating a hash based on composite keys in a collection of children objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, hash

I want to create a hash (using Base64) based on a composite of foreign keys from a collection of children objects that belong to a parent.

```
class Basket < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :basket
  belongs_to :mfg
  belongs_to :locale
end
```

So let's say that we have a basket object that has three item objects:

> **Item #1**
>   - mfg_id: 1
>   - locale_id : 2
>
> **Item #2**
>   - mfg_id: 3
>   - locale_id : 4
>
> **Item #3**
>   - mfg_id: 5
>   - locale_id : 6

The hash would like something like:

> Base64.encode64(12-34-56)

My question really is what's the most efficient way in ruby to create such a hash?  If it were just a few children objects to iterate over, then I wouldn't be too worried about efficiency; however, in my case there could be a lot so I'd like your input on the most efficient way that you can recommend to construct the hash.

Comment: Before I answer: what's your use case? Why do you need this particular hash construction? I ask because this is a little unusual.

Comment: thx for edits...makes it more readable

Comment: In my particular case I am going to use this generated hash to find out if there are any duplicate baskets in the table.  A duplicate basket would occur if there are two of the same hashes.  I could use straight SQL, but it gets very convoluted.  I'd prefer to create the hash right when the basket is created and save it to the DB.

Comment: why don't you use mysql for that? you could make a unique index across these three columns or use `validates_uniqueness_of :item_id, :scope => [:mfg_id, :locale_id]`

Comment: Probably not. Define a unique index in the DB instead if possible (which it may not be here), or (failing that) write a custom validator on the Rails side.

Comment: This isn't a matter of trying to avoid duplicates.  Duplicates are fine but my business logic requires me to understand if there are like baskets in the table.

Comment: I am looking for a solution to the given question.  That's the scope.

Comment: Sled: Great minds think alike. :)

Comment: `Model.where(:item_id => some_item_id, :mfg_id => some_mfg_id, :locale_id => some_locale_id).count`

Comment: Then don't bother with the hash and just look for like baskets. The hashing would be premature optimization.

Comment: So I've over-simplified the example above. I would agree with you if the example I gave were the exact case that I am dealing with.  It's not.  While it could be solved with SQL, it simply gets too convoluted.

Comment: Maybe you should tell us what's really going on. Sounds like you might be asking us to help you move in the wrong direction but I can't be sure.

Comment: Ok. This question is a follow-on to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542907/solution-for-finding-duplicate-records-involving-sti-and-parent-child-relation.  I liked Mike Sokolov's suggested approach.  You can correct me if you think my logic is faulty, but I'd rather not go with the SQL approach because my preference would be to keep it simple, and thus, maintainable.

Comment: SQL is simple and maintainable if you do it right, and it's the correct way to do large aggregate operations -- those should not involve the application layer if at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe:

```
basket.items.select([:mfg_id, :locale_id]).map { |i| "#{i.mfg_id}#{i.locale_id}" }.join("-")
```

There should a monstrous quantity of items for something like this to be inefficient (because of the creation of the intermediate array). You can also use inject to build the string inplace and avoid the intermediate array, but that's pretty ugly compared to `map` + `join`.

And using pure SQL (not so portable, but faster):

```
basket.items.select("GROUP_CONCAT(mfg_id, locale_id SEPARATOR '-')")
```

Comment: This is about what I came up with in the shower just after my last post as well. :) You've hit a case that SQL just doesn't handle that well, except with proprietary extensions like `GROUP_CONCAT`. Although...I think I'd just fetch an array of records, not concatenate them. They'll be easier to manipulate as an array, and you can still hash if you really need to (though personally, I'd just do array comparison).